# Using CURL to list github repository tree (github API)

Tags: api, github, tree

Using the github API, you can get a repository tree using (example done with CURL):

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/trees/{tree_sha}
```

Assuming I have a repo called *dev* by owner *NewCo*, and I want to list the repo tree called XXXX, I would:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/NewCo/dev/git/trees/{tree_sha}
```

How can I find out the {tree_sha} value for tree XXXX? Any idea where can I find out this value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a commit sha from the [commits endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#list-commits) for that: `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits`. For example:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

owner=zacanger
repo=fetchyeah

sha=$(curl -s -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/commits?per_page=1 \
  | jq -r '.[0].sha')

curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/git/trees/$sha
```

You could also use the pull requests API, or any other endpoint that returns commit info (meaning, most of them except for user and org APIs).

Comment: Getting a commit sha only seems to get the files for that commit at the top level. is there a way to make this recursive?