# Get the folder structure of the remote git repository

Tags: git, github

I want to fetch the folder structure of a remote git repo of huge size (Unreal Engine), so fetching and then analyzing is not a solution. Is there any built-in mechanism or any way to use remote git repo data to do it? I know that I can crawl GitHub and build the folder structure that way, but it seems clumsy and slow.

I looked at the git docs, but didn't find any useful commands or even closely related stuff.

Comment: Have you tried [Github API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65676058/using-curl-to-list-github-repository-tree-github-api)? `/repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`

Comment: @yusuf I wanted to try it, but [Jeremy Fiel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77582570/23018067) answer is much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have access to Unreal Engine repo, you can use a GitHub Codespace and then run `git ls-files` and you will find a directory listing.

here's one for a repo I have in a codespace.

[image: codespace]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Also, I am amazed at how fast it worked with such limited resources.